# Can ListBox row selections be "intercepted"?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

I have a `ListBox` with rows. When one of its `ListBoxRows` are clicked, it should select it normally if `foo()` returns `True`, but otherwise, it should spawn a confirmation window with the option to then select it. Only after the selection is confirmed, the clicked row should be selected.

I've implemented it this far already, but I struggle with making it play its normal button-press "animation" as well. Can I somehow make it do that?

---

If anyone else stumbles over this later, I got it working (except for the normal selection animation) using a snippet looking something like this:

```py
lbr = ListBox()
lbr.connect("row-activated", bar)

for i in rows:
   row = ListBoxRow()
   row.set_selectable(False)
   row.set_activatable(True)
   row.add(Label("Example"))
   lbr.add(row)

def bar(_, row):
   if foo(row):
      lbr.select_row(row)
```